# background-color of div not sticking when window is scaled down

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a responsive menu with buttons that will shift position if the window width is below 800px. I have accomplished this but now the background-color of the menu changes along with the buttons' position. I believe I have narrowed down the problem to my use of floating, but if I don't float the items in the `.section` class to the left, the buttons will no longer change position correctly. Why won't `#nav` inherit the correct background-color? And if floating is the cause, how could I avoid this problem? Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="nav" class="clearfix">
  <div id="left" class="section">
    <div class="button vanish">TOC</div>
  </div>
  <div id="center" class="section">
    <div class="button">Home</div>
    <div class="button">Contact</div>
    <div class="button">About</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="section">
    <div class="button vanish">Search</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
.clearfix {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
#container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    font-family: Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    font-size:15px;
    background-color:#eee;
}
#header {
    width: 94%;
    padding: 3%;
    background-color: #FF5722;
    font-family: Serif;
}
#nav {
    width: 97%;
    background-color: #E64A19;
    padding: 0 1.5% 0 1.5%;
}
.button{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 1.5% 15px 1.5% ;
}
.button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.vanish{
    display:none;
}
@media all and (max-width : 800px) and (min-width: 331px) {
    #header {
        text-align: center;
    }
    #content {
        width: 94%;
        padding: 3%;   
    }
    .sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
    .vanish{
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .section{
        display:inline-block;
        float:left;
    }
    #left{
        width:20%;
        text-align:left;
    }
    #right{
        width:20%;
        text-align:right;
    }
    #center{
        width:60%;
        text-align:center;
    }
}
```

Here is a link to a working version of the above code: http://foothillertech.com/student/webdesign/2015/2nd/g_lebon0819/index/indexTestBenrud.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the implementation of float, the respective element move to its position and rest of the elements moves up so to overcome with this sort of problem.
Use
`overflow: auto;`

In your case use it at #nav.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class of `clearfix` to element `#nav`

```
.clearfix::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

The problem is due to the reason, when there's a element with floating child, then it may not wrap them over, hence leaves zero (0) height, so styles are getting applied but on a parent with 0 height.

Answer (score 0):

**use css**

```
#nav {
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: #e64a19;
    padding: 0 1.5%;
    width: 97%;
}
```

**instead of**

```
#nav {
    background-color: #e64a19;
    padding: 0 1.5%;
    width: 97%;
}
```

**EDIT :** Oops!!! I didn't notice that same answer had already given by @Aman

feeling embarrass... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

Just add `fload:left` in `#nav` css.

```
#nav {
    float:left;
    width: 97%;
    background-color: #E64A19;
    padding: 0 1.5% 0 1.5%;
}
```